# Perl: custom sort order?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

A stenographic keyboard has the keys in a specific order: STKPWHRAO*#EUFRPBLGTS.

I am attempting to take an input $word and determine if its letters follow this order, from left to right.

So KAT would be valid, but FRAG would not be, because while F is before R on the right side, they are not before A-. TKPWAUL would work, but GAUL would not, because -G is not before A. The keys must be ordered from left to right.

I'm getting tripped up by some letters appearing twice in the order.

Thank you very much for any ieas!

Comment: What is your question, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a regex with anchors to start and end of string and allow every character 0 or one time. Here's an example:

```
sub match {
    my $yesno = $_[0] =~ /^S?T?K?P?W?H?R?A?O?\*?#?E?U?F?R?P?B?L?G?T?S?\.?$/g;
    print $_[0] . " " . ($yesno ? 'yes' : 'no') . "\n";
}
match 'KAT';
match 'FRAG';
match 'TKPWAUL';
match 'GAUL';
```

delivers

```
KAT yes
FRAG no
TKPWAUL yes
GAUL no
```

You could generate that regex from a list using `split`, `join` etc.

Comment: Are duplicates ok? Then you should match zero or more times.

Comment: In regard to being bothered by repeating letters, change the ?s to *s.

Comment: Thank you! I slaved over nested foreach loops before seeing your answer, which is much easier to follow!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark accepted. It is a fun puzzle and actually useful, a similar algorithm is used for fuzzy matching in tools like [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) and such. See the comments under [zdim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35376367/201318) for a solution with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward algorithm.  This should be efficient, and can also be improved if needed.

Iterate through the characters in the word, searching for each in the reference sequence.  Compare match's position in the sequence with the one for the previous character. Keep searching for all matches since some letters repeat in the sequence. Search uses `index`.

```
sub accept_word {
    my ($refseq, $word) = @_; 
    my ($mark, $pos) = (0, 0); 
    foreach my $ch (split '', $word) {
        # search until position is >= $mark, or the word is bad 
        while ( ($pos = index($refseq, $ch, $pos)) != -1 ) { 
            $mark = $pos, last  if $pos >= $mark;
        }   
        return 0 if $pos < $mark;
    }   
    return 1;
}   
for my $word (qw(KAT FRAG TKPWAUL GAUL SAS)) {
    print "$word is " . (accept_word($refseq, $word) ? 'accepted' : 'rejected') . "\n";
}
```

Comments:

This can be tightened quite a bit if needed.  The search can be greatly optimized since only 'S' and 'T' repeat, at start and end (see comments). Or, it can be optimized by looking up the count of letters in the sequence first (say via `('S' => 2, 'T' => 2, 'K' => 1)` etc) so that `index` doesn't do unnecessary work. See [tba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201318/kba)'s comment for his link to a slightly tighter version and a benchmark between that and his posted regex solution, which uses a different algorithm.

A detailed worded description of this step-by-step solution. Iterate through your word by characters, for each doing the following:

Traverse the reference sequence and once a match is found record its numeric index in the sequence. On the first pass (first word character) this becomes the highest position, say `$mark`.

For the rest of iterations one need be careful since the reference sequence has repeated characters. (Thanks to [tba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201318/kba) for a comment.)  As a char is found to match in the sequence, the index of the match is compared to `$mark` and if it is `>=` we reset the `$mark` to it and go to the next char. If the position is `< $mark` the search-and-comparison continues until `>=` is found or the sequence exhausted, when the word is discarded (char is to the left of the previous one).  Improvement: start the search from `$mark` and if a match is found reset `$mark` and move to next char, otherwise the word is discarded (done via `index` in the code above).  As you are matching characters in your word you are crawling up the reference sequence and remembering how far you got.

This way the word is mapped to a non-decreasing numeric sequence based in the reference string, or discarded. In the code above that numeric encoding can be recorded if needed.

Comment: If you use a hash for lookup, characters cannot be repeated. For example, `S` is the left-most and the right-most character. The word `SAS`  would be allowed but the hash- and index-versions of your algorithm would mark that as a bad word.

Comment: Corrected, thanks again.  Didn't expect that and just didn't catch it, while I understood OP's "twice in order" the wrong way round.  (Wouldn't post another comment for this but I can't edit the first one.)

Comment: Just for the heck of it, I implemented your approach (doesn't work like in the answer, you don't need `$mark` if using 3-arg `index`) and benchmarked the two, see https://gist.github.com/kba/879f3cb33311f15c4d44. Using `index` is slighly faster.

Comment: Interesting. The posted code doesn't waste (much) time and `index` is fast but I wouldn't know what exactly to expect against the regex (even as they are not speed daemons).  What you posted in the link is cleaner, I just wanted to keep it basic and to literally express the 'algorithm' (not much of an algorithm really).  My posted code works as it stands, with a handful of words I tried.

Comment: As for performance: Since the sequence seems to be a fixed thing we can make use of the fact that only S and T are doubled, at first and last places.  This may allow optimization: If char is S it just goes since it is last, no indexing needed, and so does the next one since S is first, too (skip next iteration); if it is T it need be checked whether S is next to it, otherwise it goes.  For all others, a single `index` invocation is enough.  Even though there's logic involved (a performance killer) I'd expect this to run better.  Can't do such fine tuning with regex.